# how to take both before classes while removing unused class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, css-selectors, next.js

I have a nextjs project .I am using `postcss-purgecss` to remove my `unused css` classes but I am  facing one issue .In my `style.css` file there is two `:before` class on same element.

I take help from https://purgecss.com/guides/next.html

```
 .f20 [class^="icn-"]:before,.f20 [class*=" icn-"]:before {
        font-family: 'icons' !important;
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
    }
```

.but when I compile and remove `unused css` file it remove one `before class`.I want both should be present in my bundle css file.How I will achieve this ? current output is this

```
.f20 [class^="icn-"]:before {
        font-family: 'icons' !important;
        speak: none;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-variant: normal;
        text-transform: none;
        line-height: 1;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale
    }
```

Here is my `postcss.config.js` file

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'autoprefixer',
    'postcss-flexbugs-fixes'[
      // ...(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? [purgecss] : []),
      ('postcss-preset-env',
      {
        autoprefixer: {
          flexbox: 'no-2009'
        },
        stage: 3,
        features: {
          'custom-properties': false
        }
      })
    ],
    [
      "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
      {
        "content": [
          "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
         
],
        'whitelistPatterns': [/fb20/]
      }
    ]
  ]
};
```

any update.. ?

Comment: The [readme](https://github.com/FullHuman/purgecss/tree/master/packages/postcss-purgecss) (also in the [docs](https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html#safelisting)) says there's a `safelist` option that seems to be about keeping certain rules regardless of what it might otherwise do. I'm not sure how it works, though.

Comment: but what class name i will add `        'safelist': ['icn-'], any guess ? any regex ?
`

Comment: I think you could use the [`specific selectors`](https://purgecss.com/safelisting.html#specific-selectors) form and just put your entire selectors in there as in `safelist: ['.f20 [class^="icn-"]:before', '.f20 [class*=" icn-"]:before']`.

Comment: Not working..:(